# problem with I/O exception in c++ ("cin" statement)

Tags: c++, exception, io, cin

In the following program:

```
int main(){

    std::cout<<"enter numbers to be divide"<<std::endl;
    int a,b,c;

    while(true){
        try{
            if(!(std::cin>>a>>b)){
                throw std::invalid_argument("please enter proper interger");
            }

            if(b==0){
                throw std::runtime_error("please enter enter nonzero divisor");
            }
            c=a/b;
            std::cout<<"quotient = "<<c<<std::endl;
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument e){
            std::cout<<e.what()<<"\ntry again?enter y/n";
            char c;
            std::cin>>c;
            if(c=='n'||c=='N') break;
        }
        catch(std::runtime_error e){
            std::cout<<e.what()<<"\ntry again?enter y/n";
            char c;
            std::cin>>c;
            if(c=='n'||c=='N') break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using two kinds of exception.Program is working perfectly when it throws "runtime_error" exception but goes into infinite loop when encounter "invalid_argument" exception. Actually there is problem in "`cin>>c`" statement in catch-block but can not figure out, why this is happening.

Comment: program works perfectly when i remove whole input scenario from catch-block of "invalid_argument" and put only "break" statement.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407771/c-character-to-int/2407991#2407991.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, I use two statements  to flush out cin stream.
"
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');"
since "std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()" giving error.
program is working perfectly now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `std::cin>>a>>b` encounters a non-numeric character, two relevant things happen:

- the offending character *is not consumed*;
- the fail bit of `std::cin` is set.

The latter prevents all further reads from `std::cin` from succeeding. This includes those inside your `invalid_argument` catch block and those inside subsequent iterations of the loop.

To fix this, you need to clear the state of `std::cin` and to consume the offending character. This is explained very well in the following answer pointed out by KennyTM: [C++ character to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407771/c-character-to-int/2407991#2407991).

Answer (score 0):

You can play with [exception masks](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/), you might find a preferable way to handle errors.