# why taking a character input in an integer variable returns 0 in c++?

Tags: c++

Just from my curiosity in a c++ code  i took character input in an integer variable then printed the value.
The output of the variable is 0 .But i was expecting to see an ASCII value like 65 or something else. 
What is the reason behind this ? 
I used code::blocks to run this code .

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: Check the status of `std::cin` and you'll see that it reports failing to parse a decimal integer from your character, which makes sense.

Comment: Please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: As for your problem you tell the program to read `int` input. If the input isn't an `int` then you have an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ character to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407771/c-character-to-int)